# Once the maven project was ran in tomcat using VsCode, the project name is visible in localhost:8080, but when I click on project it gives a 404

Tags: maven, tomcat, visual-studio-code, java-ee-6

LoginServlet.java
[image]
login.jsp
[image]
web.xml
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it is path mapping that you do, then the URL pattern should be started with forward-slash (/),

```
@WebServlet(urlPattern = "/login.do")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {}
```